# Is it possible to create a column in Microsoft SQL Server that limits what can be added to column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, I want to specify that an 'Email' column must contain an @ symbol in order to be valid. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

You do this using a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_email check (email like '%@%' and email is not null);
```

Of course, this is just an illustration.  An email has many other rules as well.  However, more comprehensive validation could be asked in another question.

Comment: Just a comment: a while back I looked into validating emails: it is a nightmare. You run into all sorts of issues such as special characters, escaped characters, quoted values, etc. I finally determined I would make certain they had an '@' with text on each side, from then on the users were on their own.